# When click on OptionMenu it shows black background on kitkat

Tags: android

When i am clicking on optionMenuItem on Toolbar then it shows black background . I am getting this issue on kitkat device , its working well on lollipop and higher

```
    // Toolbar which i am using 

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                local:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomPopUpTheme"
                local:theme="@style/ToolbarCustomTheme" />


    // MyCustomPopUpTheme theme it works correctly

     <style name="MyCustomPopUpTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
            <!--  item for setting the background color of item selected from the list -->
            <item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@color/white</item>
        </style>

  // ToolbarCustomTheme theme here i am getting issue extending ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar theme

    <style name="ToolbarCustomTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try always setting the alpha when defining colors. So if you want red, instead of #ff0000 define #ffff0000.

In case your @color/white is a simple #ffffff, just use the predefined @android:color/white. Theres a couple predefined ones.